# How to get dependent options values into a hidden input filed in knockoutJs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs

I am trying to get selected input values into a hidden field, can any one help me on this, up to now as i am trying with below code.

Html

```
<select data-bind="options: packages,
                   optionsCaption: 'Select...',
                   optionsText: 'name',
                   value: selectedPackage">                 
</select>
</br>
<!-- ko with : selectedPackage -->
</br>
<select data-bind="options: locationOptions,
                   optionsCaption: 'Select...',
                   optionsText: 'location',
                   value: $parent.selectedLocation">
</select>
<!-- /ko  -->
```

Display values at

```
<span data-bind="with: selectedPackage">
        <b data-bind="text: name"></b> 
            <!-- ko with : $parent.selectedLocation -->
                > <b data-bind="text: location"></b>
            <!-- /ko  -->
    </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span data-bind="with: selectedPackage">
                <b data-bind="text: price"></b> $ +  
            <!-- ko with : $parent.selectedLocation -->
                $<b data-bind="text: price"></b>
            <!-- /ko  -->
    </span>
```

Js/Knockout code

```
    this.packages = [
    {
        sku : "306",
        name: "Standard delivery hours (8-4)",
        description: "its nice",
        price: 99,
        locationOptions : []
    },
    {
        sku : "100",
        name: "Within a 4 hour window (adds $15)",
        description: "its nice",
        price: 100,
        locationOptions : [
            { location: "6:00 AM - 10:00 AM (off hours)", price: 15},
            { location: "6:30 AM - 10:30 AM (off hours)", price: 15},
            { location: "7:00 AM - 11:00 AM (off hours)", price: 15}
        ]
    },
    {
        sku : "101",
        name: "Within a 2 hour window (adds $25)",
        description: "its cool",
        price: 100,
        locationOptions : [
            { location: "8:00 AM - 10:00 AM", price: 25},
            { location: "10:00 AM - 12:00 PM", price: 25},
            { location: "12:00 AM - 02:00 PM", price: 25}
        ]
    },
    {
        sku : "102",
        name: "Within a 1 hour window (adds $40)",
        description: "its cool",
        price: 100,
        locationOptions : [
            { location: " 8:00 AM - 9:00 PM", price: 40},
            { location: "9:30 AM - 10:00 PM", price: 40},
            { location: "10:00 AM - 11:00 PM", price: 40}
        ]
    }
];


    this.selectedPackage = ko.observable();
```

Everything is working fine, but i am trying to get the selected dependent values in to a hidden filed, but values are not rendering.

```
<input id="return_order_dependent" type="hidden" name="return_order_dependent" data-bind='value: selectedPackage().name' />
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `selectedPackage` can be `null` or `undefined`. Whenever this happens, your `value` data-bind throws an error:

`selectedPackage().name` *becomes* `undefined.name` *throws* **`Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`**

The `undefined`/`null` value is a result of the `optionsCaption` binding. Without the caption, knockout wil set your selected value to the first element in the list upon applying the `select` binding.

You'll need to do 2 things:

1. Determine how you want to indicate an unset value
2. Make sure the data-bind doesn't break.

Personally, I'd use a computed and manage the unset state in your viewmodel:

```
this.hiddenInputValue = ko.pureComputed(() => {
  return (this.selectedPackage() || { name: "NOT_SET" }).name;
});
```

With data-bind:

```
<input type="hidden" data-bind='value: hiddenInputValue' />
```

You can also put this logic in the data-bind itself (this example defaults to `null`)

```
<input type="hidden" data-bind='value: selectedPackage() ? selectedPackage().name : null' />
```

Other solution directions are:

- Remove the `optionsCaption`, always select the first value by default
- Place an `if` or `with` around the hidden input (this might not work with your server related stuff)